# Running JS whenever a specific page is loaded

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, bookmarklet

I currently have a bookmarklet that I want to be executed whenever a specific page is loaded.

Is there a Chrome extension or similar that will let me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Chrome user scripts](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts).  In Chrome, you use a `@match` line like:

```
// @match http://www.google.com/*
```

to specify the page.

These are similar to Greasemonkey scripts, with some browser-specific differences.  See [this list](http://userscripts.org/tags/chrome) of scripts that work in Chrome.